# Generic type with enum type

Tags: c#, generics, enums

I'm writing code for parameter class that being used by some kind of commands. This command has two main Issues:

- OptionalValues - This is the optional values to be selected.
- SelectedValue - The user choice.

The user input is: select one member from enum.

**The code:**

```
public enum eUserChoice
{
    Choice1,
    Choice2,
    Choice3
};

public class Parameter<ENUM_TYPE>
{
    public ENUM_TYPE OptionalValues {get;} // WRONG USING
    public ENUM_TYPE Value {get; set;}
}
```

**Requested behavior of the code:**

```
Parameter<eUserChoice> myParam = new Parameter<eUserChoice>()
myParam.Value = myParam.OptionalValues.Choice1;
// OR:
// myParam.Value = myParam.OptionalValues.Choice1 | myParam.OptionalValues.Choice2;
```

When I'm writing "myParam.OptionalValues." I'm want that this will be equal to write "eUserChoice." (**intellisense** is important).

I'm not sure if it's possible...
What do you think?

Comment: It's not very generic if the type is known the entire time.. why bother with generics at all for this.

Comment: You can't do that, myParam.OptionalValues is a value not an enum type. You have to use myParam.Value = eUserChoice.Choice1;

Comment: you get intellisense anyway when you type myParam.Value =

Comment: Thank you for this information. This is pretty good for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generics are not (that) magic. With the following line

```
public ENUM_TYPE OptionalValues {get;}
```

You are creating a property that can have a *value* of type ENUM_TYPE. However what you want is to let the `OptionalValues` property link to the type itself. This is impossible.

Generics simply allow you to create some sort of class template (c++ people: not *that* kind of template) which generates a new class for each type of ENUM_TYPE you supply. And nothing more.